# ¿Para que se usa el while(1) en un bucle?

Tags: c

Navegando por la red y buscando códigos de otras personas he visto poner un 1 o `true`, pero realmente no sé cual es el propósito de esto.

```
while(1){

  //CODIGO AQUI!
}
```

Comment: Fijate como se define una variable booleana en C.. 1 es true.. cualquier otra cosa false...

Comment: Como dice @gbianchi el 1 es el equivalente de true,  el proceso encerrado en el while se mantendra activo mientras no cambie el resultado a false.

Comment: y nunca va a cambiar a false.. en gral esos programas terminan bruscamente...

Comment: pero para que salga del bucle necesitas que te retorne 1? es decir true?

Comment: @gbianchi Cualquier valor diferente de cero es verdadero, los valores `bool` en C son evaluados por sus bits, si alguno esta "encendido", entonces es verdadero, si pones `while (-1)` igual funciona.

Answer (score 8):

El `while 1` no se usa para nada en específico salvo para permitir la ejecución sin límite del contenido del ciclo, su equivalente en cualquiera de sus derivados seria:

```
while (true) {
  // Código aquí.
}
```

Se va a mantener ejecutando lo que hay en el bucle hasta que pongas alguna condición que lo haga salir con un `break` o algo parecido.

En C, es común utilizar `while (1)` para dejar esto claro: "No existe una condición lógica que sea exacta para detener este ciclo"

Por ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_BUF (1024)

int main(void) {
  int c = 0, ind = 0; char str[MAX_BUF];
  while (1) {
    printf("Escribe algo (No mas de 1024 caracteres): ");
    ind = 0; /* Reseteamos el indice. */
    while (((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n') && (ind < MAX_BUF))
      str[ind] = c, ind++;
    if (0 == strcmp(str, "salir")) /* Salimos si es necesario. */
      break;
    if (ind) /* Nos aseguramos que el usuario no presiono enter nomas. */
      printf("Has escrito: '%s'\n", str);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Fíjate que en el código anterior, solo va a salir del ciclo si la variable `str` contiene el valor `"salir"`, de igual forma puedes poner más de una condición para la salida del ciclo, pero mientras ninguna se cumpla, simplemente se seguirá ejecutando.

De hecho, puedes tratar de hacer un `while (1)` y ver como tu programa nunca finaliza. :^)

Saludos :)

Comment: Además permite saliendo del bucle en cualquier linea antes del fin como cuando llega al break en el ejemplo de NaCl.

Answer (score 0):

El proposito de dicho codigo es crear un bucle infinito.

En el mundo real el uso mas comun es prevenir que otro codigo de bloque se alcanzado, ya sea que si se alcanza algun bloque codigo fuera de dicho bucle algun error ha ocurrido o que entre en dicho bucle si algun error ha ocurrido.

Siendo el segundo tipo de uso el que se le ha dado a un archivo que forma parte del kernel de linux y puede ser apreciado en la linea 678 del archivo pc_keyb.c en su version 2.4.x.

http://www.kneuro.net/cgi-bin/lxr/http/source/drivers/char/pc_keyb.c?a=mips#L678

Comment: El enlace ha caducado, pero se puede apreciar también en la línea 226 de kdb_keyboard.c: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/debug/kdb/kdb_keyboard.c